# Zero divisors in the ring ($P(X)$ , $\tiny \triangle$ , $\cap$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set that contains more than one element.

If $A \in P(X)\setminus \{\emptyset , X\}$ then $A$ is a zero divisor in the ring $(P(X) , {\tiny\triangle}, \cap)$, where $\tiny \triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference.

**Demonstration:**

We are interested to prove that for all $A \in P(X)\setminus \{\emptyset , X\}$, $A$ is always a zero divisor in $P(X)$. Therefore, we need to search $B \in P(X)\setminus \{\emptyset \}$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

I have considered $B = X\setminus A$ and I have proved the following:

1. $[$ $A$ $\not=$ $\emptyset$ and $A$ $\not=$X $\Longrightarrow$ $B$ $\not=$ $\emptyset$ $]$ $\equiv$ $[$ $B = \emptyset$ $\Longrightarrow$ $A = \emptyset$ or $A = X$ $]$

- $B = \emptyset \Longrightarrow \emptyset = X \setminus A \Longrightarrow A = X $

2. $A$ $\cap$ $B = \emptyset$

- $A \cap B = A \cap (X \setminus A) = (A \cap X) \setminus (A \cap A) = A \setminus A = \emptyset$

Is this proof correct? I have doubts because I have not used that X contains more than one element, but I think it is an extra fact to assecure we could take a subset $A$ of $X$ distinct of $\emptyset$ and $X$.

Comment: The assumption that $X$ contains more than one element is not necessary. If there is some $A \subseteq X$ which is neither $\emptyset$ nor $X$, then it follows that $X$ has at least 2 elements, one in $A$ and another in $X \setminus A$.

Answer (score 3):

Considering $B=X\setminus A$ is good! Indeed you're right: you have implicitly used the fact that $X$ has more than one element, because if it had at most one element then $P(X)=\{\varnothing,X\}$ so we cannot take $A\in P(X)\setminus \{\varnothing,X\}$.

Comment: Thanks!! I was thinking  that exactly, but I was not too much sure

Answer (score 1):

$A\in {\scr{P}}{(X) }\setminus \{\emptyset, X\}$

Then, $A$ is a proper subset of $X$ implies $X\setminus A \neq \emptyset $

Set $B=X\setminus A$ , then $A\cap X\setminus A=\emptyset$